# My linked server from as400 disconnects every time SQL Server is restarted

Tags: sql-server, iseries, linked-server

Every time I restart SQL Server, my linked server which is linked with AS400 gets disconnected.

Every time it gets disconnected, I simply refresh the provider and I'm good to go. But, sometimes if I'm not available all the jobs stop working and I lose a lot of data.

Comment: This sounds like a doctor, doctor scenario. Why are you restarting your SQL Server in the first place? If it's scheduled maintenance you need to manage everything that connects to it as well.

Comment: Why do you expect a connection to be maintained through the database server restart?